# Dependencies in Android Gradle project (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been migrating to Gradle and I've encountered an awkward issue.

Using Intellij IDEA I found two ways to add a dependency, please see the pictures attached:

[image: the way A]

[image: the way B]

As I can see these two way are not interchangeable. But the way B is obviously equivalent to

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':xx-manager-shared')
}
```

Could anyone explain to me that's the exact difference between these two methods of adding dependencies?

And how should I organise "cross dependencies" in Gradle when
    **A** module depends on **B** module,
    **B** depends on **C**
    and **C** depends on **A**?

Answer (score 1):

It seems in A the dependencies are for the Android module, and in B it is the dependencies required by the Gradle plugin for building, e.g. Annotation processing?

I would recommend you download and try out Android Studio, it looks a lot simpler since it is purpose built for Android development, and you get a simple list of modules, without the tree hierarchy above.

I generally add dependencies by hand, as it doesn't mess up the build.gradle files.

In answering your other question, you are defining circular dependencies, so if you can find a way around it it's best, otherwise you can try adding them, syncing with Gradle and seeing if it works.